# Changing values of 2 textboxes with each other (VS.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to know how to change the values of 2 textboxes with each other when I click on a button. vs.net

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy :)

```
'Values to Store the text
Dim textbox1 as String
Dim textbox2 as String
textbox1 = mytextbox1.text
textbox2 = mytextbox2.text

mytextbox1.text = textbox2
mytextbox2.text = textbox1
```

this would be possible too

```
'Values to Store the text
Dim textbox1 as String
textbox1 = mytextbox1.text

mytextbox1.text = mytextbox2.text
mytextbox2.text = textbox1
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Nvm it worked, also, I'm really sorry if this was a very stupid question. I've started programming and working in VS.net a few days ago.

Comment: Glad to hear it before asking some new questions consider reading some books or looking things up by yourself :) (No question is stupid :)